# Programm Output "nan"

Tags: c++, math, pi

I am trying to calculate PI with the infinite series. When I started my programm I excpected to get some wrong nummbers, but instead I get the output "nan".

Does anyone know why?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long double pi;
    float x;
    int y = 3;
    bool loop = true;
    while(true)
    {
        x=1/y;
        y+2;
        if(loop == true)
        {
            pi -= x;
            loop = false;
        }
        else if(loop == false)
        {
            pi += x;
            loop = true;
        }
        cout<<pi<<" ";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `y+2;` what are you trying to do here? And, when does the loop terminate?

Comment: I don't see `pi` variable being initialized with anything.

Comment: Note that `if (loop == true)` is ordinarily written `if (loop)`. And in `else if (loop == false)`, the test is not needed. A simple `else` is sufficient, because you only get to the `else` if the first branch was not executed, i.e., if `loop` was false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of your code is undefined as *pi* is not initialised when you read its value on adding or subtracting `x` to or from it. That accounts for the NaN: some compilers helpfully - in some ways - set uninitialised floating point variables to NaN.

`x = 1 / y;` sets `x` to 0 due to integer division. Did you want `1.0 / y`?

`y + 2;` is a no-op. Did you want `y += 2`?

Note that you need to multiply the series by 4 to obtain *pi*, and this series converges especially slowly, some 300 terms are needed for two decimal places. And your starting value of `y` is wrong. Shouldn't it be 1?